# Excel Macro to grab data from other spreadsheet

Tags: excel, macros

I need to write a macro in Excel that basically takes the count of data in another spreadsheet and puts it in the current spreadsheet. For ex. Spreadsheet B has 6 rows filled in column G. I want spreadsheet A to take the number 6 and add it to its own spreadsheet. Any help is appreciated. I have never worked on macros before. Thank you

Comment: Sounds like this will be a good learning opportunity for you: don't forget to post back with your code if you run into problems.

Comment: This question is overly broad (you are essentially asking for how to write macros). Any book or tutorial will explain how to use VBA to transfer data between worksheets or workbooks (it isn't clear which you want). Start by working through such a tutorial.

Comment: You don't need a macro for this, is that a hard requirement?

Comment: These are 2 different excel documents. I would need some sort of link to attain the data from other spreadsheets.

Comment: Just open both documents and use a `=COUNTA()` function. VBA is super overkill here.

Comment: If spreadsheet as in sheets in a workbook, a COUNTA() @JNevill is right.  If they are actually two different workbooks, you will need to open Spreadsheet B, count the columns and put it on Spreadsheet A.  Read this thread or do a search on how to open excel file via VBA (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Since this doesn't seem to be going anywhere in the comments. You can refer to a closed workbook with a sheet formula. In your case, something like:

```
  =COUNTA('C:\[Book2.xlsx]Sheet1'!G:G)
```

To make this easy, open both workbooks. In workbook a type `=CountA(` and then select column G in workbook B so it will bring in the reference. Then close workbook B and you will have a formula like the one above. Done and done.

Comment: Thanks JNevil. i will try it out. Appreciate the help